# Mute system error message in a script file and display mine

Tags: bash, error-handling

I have created a simple script to move all the files with `.sh` suffix in the current working directory to a designated directory

If there was no such file, the script should output only an error message that I have entered, not the system error message: `mv: cannot stat ‘*.sh’: No such file or directory`

I tried adding `./shm 2> /dev/null` after the `mv` command put that caused the script to run with no stop!

*How can I mute the systems error message?*

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Moving all script files to script directory..."
mv *.sh $HOME/linux/scripts
#./shm 2> /dev/null
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
 then
        echo "No files with .sh suffix"
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below script should be helpful, it will help you in displaying your custom error messages.

```
#!/bin/bash

files=$(ls *.sh 2> /dev/null)

if [ -z "$files" ]
then
    echo "No script files found. Exiting.."
    exit
fi

echo "Moving all script files to script directory..."

for file in $files
do
    if ! mv $file $HOME/linux/scripts
    then
        echo "Unable to move file $file"
    fi
done
```

When the script gets executed, the list of `"*.sh"` files in the current working directory of the scripts gets assigned to `files` variable.

Next we do a sanity check to see if `$files` variable is empty. If its empty then it means that there are no `"*.sh"` files in the directory.

If the files exist, the `for` loop iterates over the `$files` variable and moves every file. If the `mv` command fails and error will be printed.

For more details about `for` loop refer [this document.](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/loops1.html)

Comment: In the for loop, what is the 'file'? And where did you define it?

Comment: The `file` variable gets defined and assigned in `for file in $files`

Comment: I guess your answer does the job, but I would like an explanation for the for loop, is it to handle the move of a file with the same name as file that already exist in the designated directory?

Comment: I have edited the answer and added more explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is wrong way to kill error message. As for me much better to use it for check.

```
#!/bin/bash

if ls *.sh &> /dev/null
then
  echo "Moving all script files to script directory..."
  mv -v -n *.sh $HOME/linux/scripts
else
  echo "No files with .sh suffix -- nothing to move"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `2>/dev/null` to you mv command to redirect stderr to /dev/null:

```
mv *.sh $HOME/linux/scripts 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding other solutions from Costas or Kannan: This

```
if ! mv $file $HOME/linux/scripts
```

should be replaced with

```
if ! mv "$file" "$HOME/linux/scripts/."
```

Also add this line somewhere at script start

```
 mkdir -p "$HOME/linux/scripts"
```

Otherwise when linux/scripts is missing, every file will be moved there as a file and overwriting the previous.

And if you have spaces in your file or folder names, the quotes will be needed.